# It is possible to run a command inside a Docker container from another container?

Tags: docker

Here's my scenario.

I have 2 Docker containers:

- C1: is a container with Ruby (but it could be anything else) that prepares data files on which it must perform a calculation in Julia language
- C2: is a container with Julia (or R, or Octave...), used to perform the calculation, so as to avoid installing Julia on the same system or container that run Ruby code

From the host, obviously, I have no problem doing the processing.
Usually when two containers are linked (or belong to the same network) they communicate with each other via a network exposing some door. In this case Julia does not expose any door.

Can I run a command on C2 from C1 similar to what is done between host and C2?
If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the two containers in the same private network? If so, have you tried accessing the other (ping, ssh) ?

Answer (score 4):

Technically yes, but that's probably not what you want to do.

The Docker CLI is just an interface to the Docker service, which listens at /var/run/docker.sock on the host. Anything that can be done via the CLI can be done by directly communicating with this server. You can mount this socket into a running container (C1) as a volume to allow that container to speak to its host's docker service. Docker has a few permissions that need to be set to allow this; older versions allow containers to run in "privileged" mode, in which case they're allowed to (amongst other things) speak to /var/run/docker.sock with the authority of the host. I believe newer versions of Docker split this permission system up a bit more, but you'd have to look into this. Making this work in swarm mode might be a little different as well. Using this API at a code level without installing the full Docker CLI within the container is certainly possible ([using a library](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api) or coding up your own interaction). A working example of doing this is JupyterHub+DockerSpawner, which has one privileged Hub server that instantiates new Notebook containers for each logged in user.

I just saw that you explicitly state that the Julia container has no door/interface. Could you wrap that code in a larger container that gives it a server interface while managing the serverless Julia program as a "local" process within the same container?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to solve the same problem. In my case, it all started when I needed to run some scripts located in another container via cron, I tried the following scenarios with no luck:

- Forgetting about the two-containers scenario and place all the logic in one container, so inter-container execution is no longer needed: Turns out to be a bad idea since the whole Docker concept is to execute single tasks in each container. In any case, creating a dockerfile to build an image with both my main service (PHP in my case) and a cron daemon proved to be quite messy.
- Communicate between containers via SSH: I then decided to try building an image that would take care of running the Cron daemon, that would be the "docker" approach to solve my problem, but the bad idea was to execute the commands from each cronjob by opening an SSH connection to the other container (in your case, C1 connecting via SSH to C2). It turns out it's quite clumsy to implement an inter-container SSH login, and I kept running into problems with permissions, passwordless logins and port routing. It worked at the end, but I'm sure this would add some potential security issues, and I didn't feel it was a clean solution.
- Implement some sort of API that I could call via HTTP requests from one container to another, using something like Curl or Wget. This felt like a great solution, but it ultimately meant adding a secondary service to my container (an Nginx to attend HTTP connections), and dealing with HTTP requisites and timeouts just to execute a shell script felt too much of a hassle.

Finally, my solution was to run "docker exec" from within the container. The idea, as [described by scnerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544215/it-is-possible-to-run-a-command-inside-a-docker-container-from-another-container/49544482#49544482) is to make sure the docker client interacts with the docker service in your host:

To do so, you must install docker into the container you want to execute your commands from (in your case, C1), by adding a line like this to your Dockerfile (for Debian):

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install docker.io
```

To let the docker client inside your container interact with the docker service on your host, you need to add /var/run/docker.sock as a volume to your container (C1). With Docker compose this is done by adding this to your docker service "volumes" section:

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Now when you build and run your docker image, you'll be able to execute "docker exec" from within the docker, with a command like this, and you'll be talking to the docker service on the host:

```
docker exec -u root C2 /path/your_shell_script
```

This worked well for me. Since, in my case, I wanted the Cron container to launch scripts in other containers, it was as simple as adding "docker exec" commands to the crontab.

This solution, as also [presented by scnerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544215/it-is-possible-to-run-a-command-inside-a-docker-container-from-another-container/49544482#49544482), might not be optimal and I agree with his comments about your structure: Considering your specific needs, this might not be what you need, but it should work.

I would love to hear any comments from someone with more experience with Docker than me!